# Identity element for `numpy.hstack`

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

How can I create an empty array wich I can then `hstack` with another array to fill with values?

For example in Matlab, I can do the following:

```
a = [];
b = [10 20];
a = [a b];
```

and would get

```
a = 

      10    20
```

I am looking for something similar in numpy. I tried

```
a = np.array([]);
b = np.array([10, 20]);
a = np.hstack((a, b)); # should be equal to `b`
```

But that gives

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: And I know, not pre-allocating arrays is a bad habit... its just for the sake of quick and dirty tryouts.

Comment: Is something wrong with `numpy.empty`?

Comment: Yes, it would create an array that has a size and values in it. I want it to be of size `(0,0)` and not contain anything. The `hstack` should then add the first few values.

Comment: `empty` allocates memory, but doesn't initialize it.  That is not what is needed here.  What is needed is, in effect, an "identity element" for the `hstack` function.

Comment: @NilsWerner So, is that true? You actually need an identity element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.array([])` with `hstack` works for me.

```
In [11]: a = array([], dtype=int)

In [12]: b = array([10, 20])

In [13]: c = array([30, 40])

In [14]: a = hstack((a,b))

In [15]: a
Out[15]: array([10, 20])

In [16]: a = hstack((a,c))

In [17]: a
Out[17]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

For `vstack`, the shape of the initial `a` needs some tweaking to make it have shape (0,2):

```
In [22]: a = array([], dtype=int).reshape(-1,2)

In [23]: a
Out[23]: array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)

In [24]: b
Out[24]: array([10, 20])

In [25]: c
Out[25]: array([30, 40])

In [26]: a = vstack((a,b))

In [27]: a
Out[27]: array([[10, 20]])

In [28]: a = vstack((a,c))

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40]])
```

Note that I've used `dtype=int` when creating the initial value of `a`. Without this, it uses the default dtype of `float`, and then when `a` is `hstack`ed or `vstack`ed with `b`, the result is upcast to float.

Comment: Interesting... I never tested it with `hstack`. It does not work with `vstack`.

Comment: You have to tweak the shape to get it to work with `vstack`--see my updated answer.  Note that the result of the first `vstack` has shape (1,2), so it is not exactly the same as `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) the dimension of `a` to match the [`shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) of `b` and fill in the missing values. This will change the size of `a` and fill it with the default value, for `np.floats` this is `0.0`

```
a = np.array([])
b = np.array([10, 20])
a.resize(b.shape)

np.hstack((a, b))
```

Comment: But it will fill it with values. The result will be `[0 0 10 20]`, not just `[10 20]`.

Comment: @NilsWerner This is true, but that is a consequence of using a numpy array. One of the reasons that numpy arrays are so fast is that they occupy a contiguous block of memory - to do that they all need to have the same `dtype`. If you want a 2,2 array of floats, there has to be a float-like object in those other entries.